# Function pointer typedef in c

Tags: c, pthreads, typedef

I have some embedded OS functions that I need to simulate on a linux machine. The approach I've been instructed to take is to overload the embedded OS functions and wrap them around POSIX threads so the linux machine can handle the embedded OS functions during unit tests and whatnot.

The embedded OS function to create a new thread is: 
`OSCreateTask(OStypeTFP functionPointer, OSTypeTcbP taskId, OStypePrio priority)`

I need to convert that `OStypeTFP` type into the void function pointer that `pthread_create` expects: (`void * (*)(void *)` is what the compiler tells me it's expecting)

I was hoping to create a typedef that I could use it like:

```
typedef void (*OStypeTFP)(void);

// Function to run task/thread in
void taskFunction(void) { while(1); }

// Overloaded Embedded OS function
void OSCreateTask(OStypeTFP tFP, OStypeTcbP tcbP, OStypePrio prio)
{
  pthread_attr_t threadAttrs;
  pthread_t thread;

  pthread_attr_init(&threadAttributes);
  pthread_create(&thread, &threadAttributes, &tFP, NULL);
}

// Creates a task that runs in taskFunction
OSCreateTask (taskFunction, id, prio);
```

but the compiler complains that `functionPointer` is of type `void (**)(void)` when pthread_create expects `void * (*)(void *)`

Do I need to change my typedef somehow, or do I need to do some typecasting? Both?

Comment: The function has to take a `void*` parameter and return `void*`

Comment: You need to read more about [`pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_create.html) and possibly about threads in general. As well as pointers to functions and functions decays to pointers and what the address-of operator does with a pointer variable.

Comment: To "overload" a function (name) is to provide different functions with the same name but different argument types.  C does not support that.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I apologize, "overload" is the wrong word to use. I need to wrap a function that LOOKS like the embedded OS function around pthread_create.

Comment: @imreal Will that work since taskFunction "takes" and "returns" void, not a void pointer?

Comment: @cjameston no, you have to change its signature, or if you cant write a wrapper that does and ignores the parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an adapter function:

```
typedef void (*OStypeTFP)(void);

// Function to run task/thread in
void taskFunction(void) { while(1); }

void *trampoline(void *arg) 
{
    OStypeTFP task = (OStypeTFP)arg;
    task();
    return NULL;
}    

// Overloaded Embedded OS function
void OSCreateTask(OStypeTFP tFP, OStypeTcbP tcbP, OStypePrio prio)
{
  pthread_attr_t threadAttrs;
  pthread_t thread;

  pthread_attr_init(&threadAttrs);
  pthread_create(&thread, &threadAttrs, trampoline, tFP);
}

// Creates a task that runs in taskFunction
OSCreateTask (taskFunction, id, prio);
```

Of course it is safe only if you system allows casts from `void *` to function pointer. But since we are at POSIX environment - it should be OK.

Comment: @BjornA. My bad. Thanks!

Comment: Ah ha! I had tried something like this before, but I tried just calling arg() instead of making a new task variable and then calling task(). Thanks!

Comment: @2501 It's true that C does not _require_ conversion between function and object pointers to work, but it does not _forbid_ that either.  And POSIX, which specifies the `pthread_*` API, *does* require conversion between function pointers and `void *` (specifically) to work.  Therefore, this answer is perfectly fine as long as there isn't any additional data that needs to be passed to the shim. Since OP is being cagey about which embedded OS they are emulating, we have no way of knowing whether they will need additional data.

Comment: @zwol Actually when I said, doesn't permit, I meant the behavior isn't defined. C does permit this as an extension, which is what posix is doing. My original comment ignores this context.

Comment: @Sergio Yes C allows conversion between void* and function pointers as an extension. J.5.7

Comment: If you were worried about the function pointer / void pointer conversion, you could pass a pointer to the function pointer instead (with a pthreads barrier to stop `OSCreateTask` returning before `trampoline` has read the function pointer value from the passed pointer).

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, the signature of a thread procedure on the embedded OS is `void thread_proc(void)`.  For POSIX threads, on the other hand, it is `void *thread_proc(void *)`.

You can't paper over this difference with casts and typedefs: you need to arrange for an appropriate return value.  You need a shim function:

```
typedef void (*OStypeTFP)(void);
struct emu_OSCreateTask_thread_start_data
{
    OStypeTFP real_thread_proc;
    // possibly other stuff
};

void *emu_OSCreateTask_shim_thread_proc (void *xctx)
{
    struct emu_OSCreateTask_thread_start_data *ctx = xctx;

    ctx->real_thread_proc();
    return 0;
}

void OSCreateTask(OStypeTFP tFP, OStypeTcbP tcbP, OStypePrio prio)
{
    pthread_attr_t threadAttrs;
    pthread_t thread;
    struct emu_OSCreateTask_thread_start_data *ctx =
        malloc(sizeof(struct emu_OSCreateTask_thread_start_data));

    ctx->real_thread_proc = tFP;

    pthread_attr_init(&threadAttributes);
    pthread_create(&thread, &threadAttributes,
                   emu_OSCreateTask_shim_thread_proc, ctx);
}
```

Note: `ctx` is allocated on the heap, and leaked, because it needs to live until after `emu_OSCreateTask_shim_thread_proc` returns, which may be indefinitely later than when `OSCreateTask` returns.  Without knowing more about the API you're trying to emulate, I can't tell you where you ought to be stashing it so that it can get freed when appropriate, but there's probably *somewhere*.  Maybe in `tcbP`?

Note 2: I use a context object instead of just stuffing the "`real_thread_proc`" in `pthread_create`'s context pointer (as in Sergio's answer) because I suspect you will wind up needing to do more stuff in the shim, and needing more data from the outer context to do it.  (You're on a POSIX system, so it *is* safe to stuff function pointers into a `void *`.)

Comment: I guess we should`free()` `ctx` before return from `emu_OSCreateTask_shim_thread_proc()`

Comment: @Sergio Not necessarily; it might wind up needing to survive until the equivalent of `pthread_join`.

Comment: @zwol This is the correct answer as it wraps the pointer in the struct. I see no reason to not free after the function call is done as pthread_join known nothing about the passed parameter. It is perfectly correct that the created thread frees the memory.

Comment: @2501 We don't know all the wrinkles of the complete API the OP is trying to emulate; we cannot say whether that is true.